# How to detect if JMX agent is running, and using which port?

Tags: java, jmx

If Java system property `com.sun.management.jmxremote` is defined at JVM start-up, the JMX agent will be started on port defined in system property `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port`.

However, there are also techniques to launch the JMX agent / listener at run-time. (See: [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) , Section: *Mimicking Out-of-the-Box Management Using the JMX Remote API*)

Is there a reliable way to detect if the JMX agent is running, and can I find the port at run-time?

Related: What happens if run-time code starts two JMX agents on different ports?

Why do I ask?  I want to auto-magically start the JMX agent on an ephemeral port if not already started.

Comment: you can get any property value at run time by `System.getProperty("property.name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to discover jmx connector servers that I have found.
However if you do start two jmx connectors then you have two ports through which you can access the PlatformMBeanServer. This shouldn't cause any harm.